# Getting Tomcat's "appBase" directory programmatically?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6

By default, appbase is configured to point to TomEE's webapps folder:

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

I would like to find the location of "appBase" programmatically because it points to different places on our production server and our development boxes (and because it'd just be cleaner that way).

I've researched a few options, and the one that seems to work for others is calling `ServletContext().getRealPath("/")`. For me this takes me to a temporary folder, `$CATALINA_HOME/temp/[#-AppName]`, while by default I was looking for `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer working off of what someone else wrote on [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19313883/accessing-a-context-specific-realm-with-tomcat-7)

From Tomcat's Host class you can find the appbase:

```
    MBeanServer mBeanServer = MBeanServerFactory.findMBeanServer(null).get(0);
    ObjectName name = new ObjectName("Catalina", "type", "Server");
    Server server = (Server) mBeanServer.getAttribute(name, "managedResource");
    Service service = server.findService("Catalina");
    Engine engine = (Engine) service.getContainer();
    Host host = (Host) engine.findChild(engine.getDefaultHost());

    host.getAppBase(); //Got it.
```

Answer (score 0):

issue using host.getAppBase() is you need to resolve it yourself (can be absolute or relative) so don't forget to use https://github.com/apache/tomee/blob/4b9d8c9d221948547d49427077fcf68709a186bd/tomee/tomee-loader/src/main/java/org/apache/tomee/loader/OpenEJBListener.java#L192

Tip: if you don't want to rely on JMX (typically new ObjectName("Catalina", "type", "Server"); depends the name you set in your server.xml and Catalina can change so you have to use a wildcard to rely on that impl) you can use *tomee* TomcatHelper.getServer() to get the server then browsing children you get the host: https://github.com/apache/tomee/blob/4b9d8c9d221948547d49427077fcf68709a186bd/tomee/tomee-catalina/src/main/java/org/apache/tomee/catalina/TomcatWebAppBuilder.java#L285